# How to solve Retrofit2 interface null pointer

Tags: java, android, interface, retrofit, retrofit2

i try to connect my server and i stuck here about 3 hours. Simply use this in another project but... anyway here is my interface and service generator. Please help me...

**ServiceGenerator**

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class ServiceGenerator {
 private ServiceInterface serviceInterface;
 private String BASE_URL = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxx/";

 public ServiceInterface init() {

          Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                 .build();
         serviceInterface = retrofit.create(ServiceInterface.class);

     return serviceInterface;
 }

 public ServiceInterface getServiceInterface() {
     return serviceInterface;
 }

}
```

**SevrviceInterface**

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;


public interface ServiceInterface {

  @GET("login.php")
  Call<LoginResponse> login(@Query("UserName") String id,
                            @Query("Password") String pass,
                            @Query("token") String token
  );  


 }
```

**xxxxxxApp**

```
import android.app.Application;

    import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.network.ServiceGenerator;
    import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.network.ServiceInterface;

    public class xxxxxxApp extends Application {
    private static xxxxxxApp instance;
    private ServiceGenerator serviceGenerator = new ServiceGenerator();

    public static xxxxxxApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        serviceGenerator.init();

    }

    public ServiceInterface getServiceInterface() {
    return serviceGenerator.getServiceInterface();
    }



}
```

**LoginAct.java**

```
public class LoginAct extends BaseActivity {

SharedPreferences preferences;

Button btn_login;
EditText edt_username;
EditText edt_pass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_login);

    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.login_btn_login);
    edt_username = findViewById(R.id.lgn_et_username);
    edt_pass = findViewById(R.id.lgn_et_pass);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            xxxxxxApp.getInstance().getServiceInterface().login(edt_username.getText().toString(),edt_pass.getText().toString(),"").enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        LoginAct.super.showToast(LoginAct.this," UserID : "+response.body().getUsers().get(0).getUser_ıd());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
}
```

And if you cath my url doesn't have SSL its http:// . My error says :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.network.ServiceInterface com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxApp.getServiceInterface()' on a null object reference
    at com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ui.LoginAct$1.onClick(LoginAct.java:40)
```

I can't figure out how to solve this i try everything i can. please help.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Can you please share the manifest application tag? 

Double-check that you mentioned the Application class name in the application tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your base url into

```
 private String BASE_URL = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx";
```

and interface into

```
 @GET("/xxx/login.php")
  Call<LoginResponse> login(@Query("UserName") String id,
                            @Query("Password") String pass,
                            @Query("token") String token
  );
```